# Copying values from multiple workbooks to specific cells in a master

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

HiHi,
*disclaimer: I have no experience with coding*
I have a code which takes values from cells (B2:C2) from multiple worksheets in a folder on my desktop and pasts it into the master workbook. This works great, however, I don't want the copied cells pasted consecutively down cells (F3:G3)- they need to be pasted into specific cells. This sounds complicated, and I'm sure it is. First, here's my base code which I have modified ([from this code](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/macro-for-copying-cells-from-multiple-workbooks.722111/)) to fit my needs:

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim WorkBk As Workbook
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim DestRange As Range

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

' Set summarysheet to activeworkbook/activesheet where the macro runs
Set SummarySheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
FolderPath = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Extracted Data\16.12.2021\"

' Call Dir the first time, pointing it to all Excel files in the folder path.
FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.csv*")

' Loop until Dir returns an empty string.
Do While FileName <> ""
    ' Open a workbook in the folder
    Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)

    'loop through all Sheets in WorkBk
    For Each sh In WorkBk.Worksheets
      
    ' Set the source range to be A9 through C9.
      Set SourceRange = Sheets(sh.Name).Range("B2:C2")
    
    ' Set the destination range to start at column B and
    ' be the same size as the source range.
    Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("F" & SummarySheet.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, _
       SourceRange.Columns.Count)
    
    ' Copy over the values from the source to the destination.
    DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value
    
    Next sh
    
    ' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
    WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False
    
    ' Use Dir to get the next file name.
    FileName = Dir()
Loop
    
' Call AutoFit on the destination sheet so that all
' data is readable.
ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit

'Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "Task Complete!"

End Sub
```

So, this runs and does copy the values from each workbook within the source folder to the master. I want to make it so that:
If it copies from a work book that contains i.e "282579" and "Ch.4" to the cells that correspond to those values. To clarify, I have added a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOgrE.png) of my master workbook.
If it copies a value from a source workbook with a title that contains 282579 and Ch.4, it will paste those 2 values into 282579's Ch.4 cell located at (F10:G10) and so on.
Tried using the If function (like, If (workbook has this in its name) but I have no idea how to specify which cells it needs to be pasted in)

I hope I have made sense and that this is understandable.

**edit: if a copy of the data I use is needed, I can supply it**

Comment: Do the workbooks have more than one sheet ?

Comment: No, every workbook (both master and sources) only has 1 sheet within.

Comment: OK you have  'loop through all Sheets in WorkBk
    `For Each sh In WorkBk.Worksheets` in you code which confused me. For the workbook 282579 and Ch.4 what is the filename is it `282579Ch.4.xlsx` with dot in filename ?

Comment: I just copied this from someone else [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/macro-for-copying-cells-from-multiple-workbooks.722111/) I suppose I don't need it but that's not the issue I'm having since it **does** copy/past into my master. The source file names are similar to this: "VS SAAV_282579 ch 4 Data" (the  **282579** and ch **4** change values). It is a .csv workbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Regular Expression to extract the SN and Ch. numbers from the filename. Use Find to located the SN on the summary sheet then scan the merged rows for the Ch number.

```vb
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()

    ' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
    Const FolderPath = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Extracted Data\16.12.2021\"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbCSV As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsCSV As Worksheet
    Dim rngCSV As Range, fnd As Range, bFound As Boolean
    Dim Filename As String, n As Long, i As Long
       
    ' Set summarysheet to activeworkbook/activesheet where the macro runs
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    
    ' regular expression to extract numbers
    ' example VS SAAV_282579 ch 4 Data.csv
    Dim Regex As Object, m As Object, SN As Long, CH As Long
    Set Regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With Regex
       .IgnoreCase = True
       .Pattern = "(_(\d+) +ch +(\d+) +Data)"
    End With
    
    ' Call Dir the first time, pointing it to all Excel files in the folder path.
    Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*Data.csv*")
    
    ' Loop until Dir returns an empty string.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While Filename <> ""
        
        ' extract SN and Ch from filename
        If Regex.test(Filename) Then
            Set m = Regex.Execute(Filename)(0).submatches
            SN = m(1)
            CH = m(2)
            Debug.Print Filename, SN, CH
            
            ' Find SN
            Set fnd = ws.Range("B:B").Find(SN, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If fnd Is Nothing Then
                 MsgBox SN & " not found !", vbCritical, Filename
            Else
               ' find ch.
               bFound = False
               For i = 0 To fnd.MergeArea.Count - 1
                    If ws.Cells(fnd.Row + i, "D") = CH Then ' Col D
                        bFound = True
                        ' Open a workbook in the folder
                        Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True)
                        ws.Cells(fnd.Row + i, "F").Resize(, 2).Value2 = wbCSV.Sheets(1).Range("B2:C2").Value2
                         ' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
                        wbCSV.Close savechanges:=False
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                If bFound = False Then
                    MsgBox "Ch." & CH & " not found for " & SN, vbExclamation, Filename
                End If
            End If
            n = n + 1
        Else
            Debug.Print Filename & " skipped"
        End If
        ' Use Dir to get the next file name.
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
        
    ' Call AutoFit on the destination sheet so that all
    ' data is readable.
    ws.Columns.AutoFit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    'Message Box when tasks are completed
    MsgBox n & " csv files found.", vbInformation, "Task Complete!"

End Sub
```

Comment: This works absolutely fantastically so far, thanks so much! Lastly, how would I edit the code to include file names that have a 'v2' such as **VS SAAV_282579v2 ch 4 Data.csv**?

Comment: @inuity_ Change the pattern in the regex to `.Pattern = "(_(\d+).*ch +(\d+) +Data)"`

Comment: Hi again, another quick question: usually the files have a space after ch like 'ch 4', how can I make it still read the files even if there is no space after since it misses these? Instead of 'ch 4' there is also 'ch4'.

Comment: @inuity `ch +` matches 1 or more spaces, `ch *` matches 0 or more, `ch ?` matches 0 or 1 space.

Comment: I've now got some data files which include HM in the file name `VS SAAV_411717 ch 2 HM Data` but it still follows the same pattern. I've tried to include HM in the `.pattern`  it's not working. How do I make it read HM?

Comment: @Inuity_ probably just need an a 0 or more characters before data like `.Pattern = "(_(\d+) +ch +(\d+) .*Data)"`

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation it is not clear if you are able to match the source worksheets with a specific Ch. If you can, I'd advise to define a Ch variable soon after the For each sh loop, then you need to initiate another loop in the master workbook on column D for each row until you get the row number of the Ch variable. You use the row number to define the destination range

```
Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim WorkBk As Workbook
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim DestRange As Range
Dim n As Long 'Ch substring position
Dim Ch As String 'Ch variable for source file
Dim LastChRow As Long 'lastrow of Ch in summary sheet
Dim ChSummary As String 'Define the Ch string in summary sheet


'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

' Set summarysheet to activeworkbook/activesheet where the macro runs
Set SummarySheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
' Define LastChRow
LastChRow = SummarySheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
FolderPath = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Extracted 
Data\16.12.2021\"

' Call Dir the first time, pointing it to all Excel files in the 
folder path.
FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.csv*")

' Loop until Dir returns an empty string.
Do While FileName <> ""



'define starting charachter of Ch source file for string manipulation
n = InStr(FileName, "Ch")

'define Ch variable
Ch = Trim(Mid(FileName, n, 5))
 
' Open a workbook in the folder
Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
 'loop through all Sheets in WorkBk
For Each sh In WorkBk.Worksheets
    For i = 3 To LastChRow
        'Define ChSummary variable in loop
        ChSummary = "Ch" & " " & SummarySheet.Range("D" & i)
        
        If ChSummary = Ch Then
    
        ' Set the source range to be A9 through C9.
        Set SourceRange = Sheets(sh.Name).Range("B2:C2")
        
        ' Set the destination range to start at column B and
        ' be the same size as the source range.
        Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("F" & i & ":G" & i)
        'Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, _
        '   SourceRange.Columns.Count)
        
        ' Copy over the values from the source to the destination.
        DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value
        
        End If
        
    Next i
    
Next sh

' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

' Use Dir to get the next file name.
FileName = Dir()'
```

Comment: Exactly, I can have the code paste the values from all the sources but I am unable to make it that if source workbook has a name 'xxxxxx' + 'ch.x' it will past into the master with the corresponding cell name 'xxxxxx' and 'ch' as you can see with the screenshot.

Comment: I added a code proposal in my previous answer according to your information. I don't think you need the loop through sh.Name if the sheet name is consistent for all csv. I kept it there in any case